# Cannot download files on android but PC can

Tags: android

We have a file we placed in a virtual directory to allow downloading.  Basically a direct file link like http:mywebserver/myapp/downloads/myfile.apk.  On a PC we can get directly to that file and it downloads.  On our mobile devices we go to that link and it begins the process to download but fails.  It just says unsuccessful download with no other relevant information.

So I thought I'd try with any other file (pdf's, word, etc) same result.  The devices are connected to our local intranet and can get to the site with no problem, you can even see a directory listing of the files.

I've already added MIME type for apk, and such but that really doesnt help.  What is stop our mobile devices from downloading these files?  I tried the android browser (the default one), chrome, and opera all on samsung galaxy s3/s4 devices but still no luck.

I have researched it here as well: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19951 but it seems to be a bit inconsistent with some folks saying they had success with opera for instance.

Comment: Does the website require a username and password?  If so its an android bug that has persisted for years.

Comment: Yes it does require your windows credentials...err an android bug for years...that scares me..and there is no workaround?  How in the heck...its almost like they want you to pay for the private google play store.

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: Mouse over the down arrow; the popup says "*This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful*".  Downvotes without comment may be presumed to be for at least one of those reasons.

Comment: MadHatter - I researched this via google - I'm not a noob.  The research was inconsistant with some saying they could do it via opera..others saying they cant.  Have a look yourself https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19951  Please don't assume people do not research - that is far from it.

Comment: OK, but you didn't **tell** us any of this.  It takes you more time to write a better question, but it saves us time in answering it.  Guess whether the community appreciates that - and disapproves of the failure to do it?  Note the text says "*the question does not **show** any research effort*" - the downvoter is making no assumptions about what you **did**, but only some *prima facie* correct ones about what you **wrote**.

Comment: @MadHatter - So ask if I researched it first - *then* downvote if I havent.  The stackexchange sites also give you a user profile.  Here you can easily tell if someone is new or not.  I also edited the question to state that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android has had issues downloading files from password protected sites.  You can browse just fine but downloads fail and don't give any indication as to why.

For a long time I had to use firefox on android to download them.  Recently that broke for sites using NTLM.

The latest google chrome on my Samsung Note 2 (android 4.1.2) does work with password protected downloads, even with NTLM authentication.

So whether it works depends a lot on the browser and android version. But newer versions do finally seem to handle it ok in chrome.

Update: As of March 2015, Chrome is back to being broken for downloads with NTLM authentication.  But Firefox works again.

Comment: So the answer is to get chrome on the android phone...awesome answer thank you.